# Geometry Nodes:"Distribute Points on Faces" vs "Set Material" selection discrepancy

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

*[I butchered the question with a heavy hand, you can still access the previous revision [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/297988/2) - MVB]*

I use the same field for *Selection* of those nodes:

- Distribute Points on Faces
- Set Material

and yet the first node distributes some points on faces, where a material wasn't set by the second node. What causes this discrepancy and how to fix it?

[image]

The Selection field:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your .blend? First thing I'd try is to remove "Points to Volume" and instance icospheres on the points, to make sure those pixels aren't some other artifact. Also perhaps you have some vertical faces that are invisible in this perspective, but spawn points which still are visible…

Comment: @Markus von Broady I am using some purchased nodes so I can't share the blend. I will try to generate the terrain without those nodes. As far as invisible faces there are only two materials on the separated plane, the blue water texture and the red selection color.

Comment: You can apply the geonodes before the problematic nodes, sharing only the product of proprietary custom groups, not the groups themselves.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I will attempt that.

Comment: Here is the link. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10L1RzTPliOTan_TMn3Uo1wMH_D2E7-dD/view?usp=drive_link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

### [Set Material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/material/set_material.html#inputs)

> **Selection**
>
> Whether to change the material of **each face**[…]

### [Distribute Points on Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/distribute_points_on_faces.html#inputs)

> **Selection**
>
> The selection of which **face corners**[…]

Therefore the difference comes from the fields being evaluated in different domains: face vs face corner. Possible solutions:

- using *Evaluate on Domain* node before one of the pair of problematic nodes, and switching the domain to the domain used by the other node,
- capturing an attribute in face domain, and reading the captured attribute, as that face → face corner interpolation is an exact copy of a value,
- setting a material first, and then using a material index for the selection.

[image]

Comment: That Did the job. Thank you for the answer along with the why things were behaving inconstantly. **Very Thorough Great job :)**

Comment: @Grandpa3D We tend to express a thank you with an upvote here. ;-)